# Select top 10 posts ordered by quantity of votes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one for image records (posts) and the other one is for likes records. So i made an INNER JOIN from one table to another because i needed to select the image and the quantity of likes that particular image has. but i also need to order them by the quantity of likes so i can make a top 10 of most voted images on the site, so here is my query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT B.votes),
  A.id_image,
  A.image,
  A.title
FROM likes_images AS B INNER JOIN images AS A ON A.id_image = B.id_image
GROUP BY A.title
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT B.votes) ASC
LIMIT 10
```

It works, but it's only ordering the images by the title (Alphabetical). I want to order them from the most voted to the less voted.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most SQL implementations, `GROUP BY criterion` *implies* any `ORDER BY` clause to be ignored in favor of `criterion`.

So you might try this:

```
SELECT L.id_image, A.image, A.title,
  * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(votes) AS likes, id_image
    FROM likes_images
    GROUP BY id_image
  ) AS L
JOIN images B ON B.id_image = L.id_image
ORDER BY L.likes DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Note that I set `ORDER BY` to `DESC` (since you want top10 I don't understand you chose `ASC`)!